# Flutter - Admob - Display banner just on one page

Tags: firebase, flutter, admob

I want to display my adBanner only on one page, nothing else.

Currently, when I click on my page and I go back instantly, my ad loaded, and displayed on my main page.

I partialy fix this with:

**Second screen**

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState(); 
  FirebaseAdMobService().showBannerAd();
} 
@override
dispose() async {
  FirebaseAdMobService().hideBannerAd();
  super.dispose(); 
}
```

**AdmobService**

```
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    
class FirebaseAdMobService {
  static final FirebaseAdMobService _singleton = FirebaseAdMobService._internal();
  FirebaseAdMobService._internal();
  factory FirebaseAdMobService() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  BannerAd _adBanner;
  bool _hide = false;

  init() async {
    await FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: "...");
  }

  static const MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
    keywords: <String>['foo', 'bar'],
    childDirected: true,
    nonPersonalizedAds: true,
  );

  BannerAd _createBannerAd() {
    return BannerAd(
      adUnitId: kReleaseMode ? "..." : BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
      size: AdSize.banner,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("BannerAd event $event");
      },
    );
  }

  void showBannerAd() {
    _hide = false;
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      if (_hide) {
        return;
      }
      if (_adBanner == null) {
        _adBanner = _createBannerAd();
      }
      _adBanner.load().then((loaded) {
        _adBanner.show(anchorType: AnchorType.bottom);
        _hide = false;
      });
    });
  }

  void hideBannerAd() async {
    _hide = true;
    await _adBanner?.dispose();
    _adBanner = null;
  }
}
```

With this, my ad is displayed after 2 seconds, but if you time the ad display (press back **just** after 2 seconds), the ad will displayed on the main page... and with my UI, block my bottom tab control.

How to prevent my ad from appearing elsewhere than on my second screen?

Thanks